# openxml-sdk - Creating word 2007 file with settings.xml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, openxml

I am trying to generate a new Word document using the following code. The Word document gets generated without settings.xml. I need to have settings.xml in the word file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static byte[] GenerateNewDocument()
{
    byte[] returnValue = null;
    MemoryStream stream = null;
    WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = null;

    try
    {
        stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Close();
        }

        throw;
    }

    using (wordDoc)
    {
        wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());             
        mainPart.Document.Save();
    }

    returnValue = stream.ToArray();
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own `DocumentSettingsPart` and then insert it into the `MainDocumentPart`. So the settings part may look like this:

```
<w:settings xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vm" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main">
 <w:defaultTabStop w:val="475"/>
 <w:compat>
 <w:compatSetting w:name="compatibilityMode" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="14"/>
 </w:compat>
</w:settings>
```

And then having that saved somewhere as "settings.xml", you could use code like this:

```
private static void AddSettingsToMainDocumentPart(MainDocumentPart part)
    {
      DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = part.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
      FileStream settingsTemplate = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      settingsPart.FeedData(settingsTemplate);
      settingsPart.Settings.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Could the content of the settings.xml be in a local variable and one can use that?

Comment: yes, it can either be one that you have prefabricated, such as the example I gave above, or you could dynamically create it using the part's members, as on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.documentsettingspart_members.aspx.

Comment: Otaku, Thanks. I have used that approach and that works. Could you please help me in this question as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877182/open-xml-using-stylepaneformatfilter-attribute-to-show-normal-style-along-wit

Comment: @user740431: Great. If the above worked for you, you can go ahead and accept it as the answer that fits your needs (click on the hollow checkmark). I've looked at the other question and it stumped me - I'm not sure if it can be done.

Comment: @user740431: I don't believe so. I tried configuring this in the client as well and it didn't work.